# C++ Memory Management and Virtual memory Page size

Tags: c++, memory-management, operating-system

Can someone explain me the relation between C++ new and Virtual memory page size. OS divides physical memory into page (usually 4K) for which are mapped into virtual memory. I want to understand how C++ new/delete affects allocation of page.

Thanks
Nayeem

Comment: When you get down to it, `operator new` uses the OS API to ask for memory. It's just another way of making the request. The fact it's through a built-in operator doesn't mean something else is happening.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901034/virtual-v-physical-memory-in-assessing-c-c-memory-leak.

Comment: The C++/C library will have to ask the operating system for memory, one way or another. Depending on the method it may receive memory in a 4k granularity (but of course serve subsequent malloc()s from that page until it is exausted). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation#Overview_of_functions for an overview.

Comment: Thanks for replies, now if i want to optimize my program i will not see any change until my malloc/new releases memory to OS. For our product we did lot of optimization but we could see any difference in amount of RAM used when compared to older versions. Its hard for me to convince my manager to allow me to spend dev resources for optimization. Is there any guide/tool which helps in reducing memory foot print of a process?

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of gross oversimplification:

There is no real relationship between page size and new. Most C++ implementations call malloc () for actual memory allocation within new.

Most malloc implementations manage a heap memory pool. When a call to malloc makes a request that cannot be fulfilled by the current memory pool, malloc calls operating system service to enlarge the pool.

This step is normally performed by requesting the OS to map additional pages into the process virtual address space.

Thus, the malloc pool size will be increments of the page size. However, malloc/new generally ignores the page boundaries.

Delete/free tends to simply return memory to the malloc pool. Deleted memory pages do not get deallocated as pages.

A new/malloc implementation may allocate the memory in many different ways. Some allocate memory in fixed sizes (usually giving excess). Others allocate memory for the size requested.

Comment: Thanks for replies, now if i want to optimize my program i will not see any change until my malloc/new releases memory to OS. For our product we did lot of optimization but we could see any difference in amount of RAM used when compared to older versions. Its hard for me to convince my manager to allow me to spend dev resources for optimization. Is there any guide/tool which helps in reducing memory foot print of a process?